# Как реализовать правильно мобильное приложение для сайта

Tags: angularjs, mobile-web, ionicframework

Есть например такой  [сайт](http://m.citilink.ru) открыв консоль (Ctrl + F12) можно легко увидеть на чем построен сайт. По DOM дереву видно применение [ionicframework](http://ionicframework.com/)  в связке с angularjs. Вопрос в том есть ли смысл использовать подобные технологии для реализации мобильного приложения? Мне в результате нужно получить приложение корректно работающее на устройствах и работающая СЕО (!важно). Для разработки фронтенда планируется angular (SPA) + api.

Comment: Ionic - это не просто AngularJS, а ангуляр + нативные функции устройств в связке с кордовой. Поэтому если вы планируете использовать нативные функции устройства, то вам он нужен.

Comment: @mix, ионик вообще с ангуляром не связан.

Comment: @Grundy вы ошибаетесь. За основу Ionic взят AngularJS

Comment: @mix, но для его работы ионику не нужен ангуляр

Comment: @Grundy вам лучше прочесть документацию и посмотреть на пример кода.

Comment: @mix тойсть я могу использовать приложение как на сервере чисто для мобильной версии сайта и если понадобится сгенерить приложение для мобильного?

Comment: @modelfak по сути, да.

Comment: @mix, да, я уже использовал его, правда с ангуляром. Возможно смутило то, что специфичные вещи были реализованы как обычный объект и просто обернуты в ангуляровский сервис.